# How/Where is table structure(not data) stored in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I know that the data in SQL Server is stored in Data pages, But I don't know where the table structure is stored. I came across a statement about TRUNCATE as

"TRUNCATE removes the data by deallocating the data pages.TRUNCATE removes all rows from a table, but the table structure and columns remains"

This made me realize that, table structure, column information is stored outside pages(or Data pages in particular). SO, How/Where is table structure(not data) is stored in SQL server ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are system tables that store all of the metadata about the database. These tables are not directly queryable (except when using the [DAC](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178068(v=sql.105).aspx)) but there are numerous views and functions built atop these tables. These are referred to as the [Catalog Views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174365.aspx).

So, for instance, there is the [`sys.columns`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms176106.aspx) view which describes each column in the database. It's a view built atop the `syscolpars` table, which is one of the system tables mentioned above that you cannot directly query.

There are also the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views which [hespi mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40374846/15498). These are meant to be a "standard" way of accessing metadata supported by all SQL database systems. Unfortunately, support for them is not 100%, and because they're meant to be cross-platform, they do not tend to reveal advanced features that are product specific.

Answer (score 2):

You can access SQL server metadata on INFORMATION_SCHEMA. Following find the most useful views and its content:

- **INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES**: Contains information about the schemas, tables and views in the server.
- **INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS**: Full information about the table columns like data type, if it's nullable...
- **INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS**: Containing information about the views and the code for creating them again.
- **INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE**: Information about foreign keys, unique keys, primary keys...

To use them, simply query them as they are data views: `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`

For a full reference go to MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx

Answer (score 1):

A SQL Server Database consists of 2 Files (usually):

- Master Data File (*.mdf)
- Transaction Log File (*.ldf)

)The Master Data File contains: Schema and Data Information

)The Transaction Log Files contains Log Information for Actions in your DB

If you run `select * from sys.database_files` in your DB it will show you the filenames, location, size, etc..